# How to let the page stay on the same location on refrsh (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, refresh

When I refresh my website, it scrolls down automatically.
I need to let the page stay on the same location after refrsh.
So, I tried the following codes but they don't work as intended.
(I put the code in the header menu template)
Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

These two codes don't work (let the page scrolls down then scrolls up again):

```
jQuery (document).ready(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

```
jQuery (document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 1);
});
```

This code doesn't work (scroll down the page) :

```
jQuery(window).on('unload', function() {
   jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why does the page scroll in the first place? You should look for the script that is causing the document to scroll and fix that instead of trying to override it. It might be caused by a plugin or a custom script that you added previously.

Comment: Hi iismaell: thank you for your comment. It seems it happened after installing WPML plugin. I'm a newbie and very clumsy.. I don't have the skill to debug, so I can only override it...